# Eureka Ribbon Client not working after upgrading to spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.2.7.RELEASE

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

So, we upgraded spring-cloud-netflix libraries from `2.2.2.RELEASE` to `2.2.7.RELEASE`. I was not expecting major hiccups but upon testing I kept seeing this error.

```
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: dummy-service
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
```

We are also using Netflix Zuul with spring `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul:2.2.7.RELEASE`.

Upon further debugging, I found that implementation of the `ServerList` property in `DynamicServerListLoadBalancer` is actually `ConfigurationBasedServerList` and not `DomainExtractingServerList` (which is supposed to wrap `DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList`). This observation also contradicts with the expected behavior in the spring-cloud docs [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html#_using_ribbon_with_eureka)

> When Eureka is used in conjunction with Ribbon (that is, both are on the classpath), the ribbonServerList is overridden with an extension of DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList, which populates the list of servers from Eureka. It also replaces the IPing interface with NIWSDiscoveryPing, which delegates to Eureka to determine if a server is up. The ServerList that is installed by default is a DomainExtractingServerList.

I also noticed that my `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.2.7.RELEASE` is downloading `spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:3.0.2` transitively which does not have `EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration` and `DomainExtractingServerList`. **Is that intentional?**

```sh
 +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix:jar:2.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:3.0.2:compile
```

I was expecting 2.x to work with 3.x since the library is being pulled transitively but that is not happening here.
BTW, I also tried to add `spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.2.7.RELEASE` inline in my pom file to override 3.0.2 but then ran into some class definition not found errors.

What is the suggestion in this case? Should I create a `EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration` inside my application so that I can get the correct `ServerList` injected? `EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration` seems to be doing much more than create a `ServerList` bean implementation.
I cannot use `3.0.2` because I am also using Zuul and Spring-cloud-zuul is maxed out at [2.2.7.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul/2.2.7.RELEASE).

I really need to keep using Spring-cloud, Zuul, Ribbon and Eureka.

**Update** Here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cdm</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-internal-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>${default.version}</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <default.version>DEV-SNAPSHOT</default.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>     
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
        <springfox.version>2.9.2</springfox.version>
        <spring-cloud.extras.version>2.2.7.RELEASE</spring-cloud.extras.version>
    </properties>

  
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.extras.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.extras.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.extras.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- API -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Runtime -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: You have something messing up the dependencies. 2.x and 3.x do not work together. Can you show your pom.xml? The 2.x versions of spring cloud do not work with boot 2.4.x.

Comment: Thanks for responding Spencer! I added my pom file in the question and can confirm I am trying this with spring boot 2.4.x.

Comment: As I suspected, this mixing of 2020.0.x and Netflix 2.x is not supported and will not work.

Comment: So, Netflix 2.x cannot work with Cloud 2020.0.x and there is no 3.x for Spring Cloud Zuul. Does that mean that my only option is to get rid of Zuul and adopt Spring Cloud Gateway if we want to keep upgrading Spring Cloud? I do not mind that since Zuul 1 is  deprecated anyways.

Comment: That is correct